# Writing a bash script for checking filenames in a directory by using an array with specific conditions

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, list, file-listing

There is a directory including several XML files.

Each filename has the following format:
**yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss-AUFXXXXXXXXX.xml**

Some XML filenames have the same number which is coming after **AUF** because they've been modified.
I want to have a bash script which should recognize these kinds of files, keep the origin ones by checking the timestamps and move the modified files to another folder.
I'm trying to write bash script to solve this issue. This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a filelist
shopt -s extglob

for file in $(ls -tr1 *AUF*); do
  filelist=(${filelist[@]} "$file")
  echo "${file}"
done
```

part of output:

```
2019-11-14-17-44-04-AUF19000276.xml
2019-11-15-09-12-01-AUF19000276.xml
2019-11-15-09-27-26-AUF19000276.xml
2019-11-15-09-28-51-AUF19000276.xml
2019-11-18-13-50-34-AUF19000296.xml
2019-11-20-16-45-14-AUF19000300.xml
2019-11-27-12-16-25-AUF19000292.xml
2019-11-27-12-19-50-AUF19000225.xml
2019-11-27-17-11-04-AUF19000300.xml
2019-11-28-09-40-44-AUF19000294.xml
2019-11-29-17-03-33-AUF19000305.xml
2019-11-29-17-04-43-AUF19000306.xml
2019-11-29-17-05-41-AUF19000306.xml
2019-12-02-12-02-20-AUF19000305.xml
2019-12-02-12-03-00-AUF19000305.xml
2019-12-03-09-22-06-AUF19000307.xml
2019-12-04-10-49-03-AUF19000308.xml
2019-12-05-09-23-54-AUF19000310.xml
2019-12-05-09-24-41-AUF19000310.xml
2019-12-09-13-12-31-AUF19000256.xml
2019-12-09-13-59-42-AUF19000256.xml
2019-12-09-15-29-25-AUF19000281.xml
2019-12-09-15-30-13-AUF19000281.xml
2019-12-09-15-34-07-AUF19000284.xml
2019-12-09-15-39-39-AUF18000346.xml
2019-12-09-15-40-21-AUF19000058.xml
2019-12-10-16-19-35-AUF19000312.xml
2019-12-11-11-58-55-AUF19000313.xml
```

For example: I want to keep the first created file **2019-11-14-17-44-04-AUF19000276.xml** and move the other three files with the same number to another directory.

I currently don't know how to check through the array and include the above-mentioned conditions.
Glad for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following (minus the `echo`) will do the job ...

```
# iterate over the AUF* parts
for i in $( ls | sed -r 's/^.*(AUF[^.]+)\.xml/\1/' | sort -u )
# iterate over the sections, move all but the first (oldest) files
do for j in $( ls -1 *${i}*| tail -n +2 )
    do echo mv $j newdir
    done
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the output looks sane =}

Comment: Thanks for your great help! It worked perfectly. I'm still wondering how it would look like if you solved this issue by using an array and checked through it with for loop but I assume your way makes even more sense on this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
dest="another"          # folder to store the modified files
mkdir -p "$dest"
declare -A seen         # associative array to count AUFXXX substring
while IFS= read -r f; do
    auf="${f##*-}"      # extract the substring after "AUF"
    auf="${auf%.*}"     # remove extension
    (( seen[$auf]++ )) && mv -- "$f" "$dest"
                        # if the AUFXXX substring is seen then move the file
done < <(find . -name "*AUF*.xml" -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -n | cut -f 2-)
```

It extracts the `AUFXXX` substring from each file and counts up the appearance in the associative array `seen`. If the value of `seen` is nonzero, then the file is a modified one and move it to another directory.